# Show Out of the Box Page within Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, aura

In a custom Lightning Aura component, is it possible to render an out of the box Salesforce page or a page built with the Lightning App Builder within the layout of the custom component?

For example, if I wanted to show the Case view page inside a custom layout, is there a way to reference that page like:

```
<aura:component>
    <!-- My custom layout stuff -->
    ...

    <!-- Show the out of the box case view page -->
    <lightning:showOOTBPage object="case" mode="view" recordId="1234567890" />
    ...
</aura:component>
```

Also, is it possible to show that page in a modal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For rendering out of the box record detail page you can use . A force:recordView component represents a read-only view of a record. You can display the record view using different layout types. There are two different types:

- MINI
- FULL (default)

[Salesforce Documentation: recordView](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_force_recordView.htm)

Comment: That looks promising but I tried and it rendered no html `<div class="my-case-view"><force:recordView recordId="500g000000Fw2kYAAR" type="MINI"/></div>` - renders as - `<div class="my-case-view" data-aura-rendered-by="523:0"><!--render facet: 3:487;a--><!--render facet: 526:0--></div>`. The record Id used was from an existing Case record that I can see in Salesforce. Any idea why this might happen?

Comment: Interestingly, `<force:recordEdit />` renders fine....

Comment: And using `type="FULL"` in renderView works fine too. Seems like `type="MINI"` is not working for me but that is probably OK. Thanks